# Notation for generalisation of summation

Tags: summation, notation

For a proof in one of my papers I need to generalize two functions into 1. I am more than uncertain whether my attempt meets the standards in this forum (I apologize in advance for the imprecice and most certainly wrong language - I am an economist not a mathematician).

I have two different expressions for $C_{\Gamma \; n}$, that depend on realisations of $\Gamma \in \{D,F\}$ :
\begin{equation}
C_{D \; n} = \sigma^D_n M_{n \rightarrow n} \\
C_{F \; n} = \sum_{m \neq n} \sigma^F_m M_{m \rightarrow n}
\end{equation}

(Intuition: Consumption of domestic goods in country $n$ is a function of (i) a preference parameter for domestic goods produced in country $n$ and (ii) goods produced in country $n$ for consumption in country $n$, while consumption of foreign goods in country $n$ is the sum of functions of (i) preference parameters for foreign goods produced in country m and (ii) goods produced in country $m$ for consumption in country $n$)

I would like to generalise those into one, in the lines of:
\begin{equation}
C_{\Gamma \; n} = \sum_{m \in F(\Gamma(n))} \sigma^{\Gamma}_{m} M_{m \rightarrow n}
\end{equation}

where $ F(\Gamma(n))$ defines the set {m = n} if $\Gamma = D$ and a set with all countries $m \neq n$ otherwise

Is this it?